# using Java Desktop.open( FIle f ) and knowing that the application is done

Tags: java, class, process, desktop

It appears that using the Java Desktop.open( File f ) to open a file with the default app that it is associated to on the user's desktop does not give me information on when the user is done with this file.  How would one find out when ther user has truly finished with this child process ?  Is there something more elegant than checking the file size every once in a while - something that only tells me that the file has been saved.

Comment: Checking the file size might not even tell you the file has been saved, since the size _might_ be equal even if the content has changed.

Comment: @Thomas indeed you are right. Check my answer below on the appropriate way of achieving this in Java.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to watch a file/directory for changes done by some other process then the [Java Watch Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) is for you. This API should help you watch a file/directory and get notified when it is touched by another process.

Comment: Wow, pretty cool stuff, wasn't aware of this api! How is the performance (memory and processor usage)? Anyhow, I voted one up for this suggestion.

Comment: By the way:how come this question is open for over a month, and within 5 minutes of my answer, you suggest this? :)

Comment: @michel.iamit Hehehe, thanks for the up vote. I just saw this question, I must have missed it a month ago :p

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can check it using Desktop.open. I suggest using the method before the Desktop class was introduced. Than you can follow the process, and trigger when the process ends....

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process proc = rt.exec(the app and file here);
```

Note: after this answer, a better suggestion was posted by GETah (which I voted up). I'll leave this answer as well, for some case this might be sufficient and easy to impelement.